# Does AngularFire use Firebase's REST API?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Does the AngularFire service use REST under the hood?

If so is there no limits in the hacker plan, because the [Firebase page on pricing](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html) says:

> REST API requests don't count towards your connection limits

?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my answer below is correct for AngularFire, but was intrigued enough by your documentation quote to post a follow-up quesion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28238298/209103

Answer (score 3):

The AngularFire library uses Firebase's regular JavaScript/Web SDK under the hood. Each client keeps a connection open to Firebase servers, so will count towards the connection limits.

You can easily verify this yourself by creating a minimal AngularFire client and opening it in a few different browsers. After 15-20 minutes you can see the connections showing up in the Analytics tab of your Firebase dashboard.